# How to create multiple alarms on a day and this will repeat on selected days on week?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I'm making an application that user can select days of week and multiple times on that day. like an alarm fire on Tuesday 8.00 AM and 2.00 PM

Answer (score 0):

Your application will have to manage those different alarms.

Put the alarms into a table and then monitor that table periodically.
Use the class android.provider.AlarmClock for setting or dismissing alarms.

checkout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#AlarmClock()